# Orbital period of two planets

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

There is the question #80 from GRE1777 https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/practice_book_physics.pdf which goes as follows:[image]

I tried to replace M from Keppler's law with the reduced mass of the system, but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At each instant, the gravitational force from the star and the gravitational force from the planet on the opposite side are in the same direction, so you can simply add them together.  The total force is

$$ F = m\left(\frac{GM}{r^2} + \frac{Gm}{(2r)^2}\right)$$

If you put this in the form

$$ F = m\frac{GM'}{r^2}$$
then you'll have your answer.